# Converter dados de campo Data para Mês Mysql

Tags: mysql, data

Em uma tabela do BD tenho um Campo 'Data' (0000-00-00) e preciso fazer o seguinte:
Criar um campo ao lado 'Mês' que pegue a data Ex: 2014-08-27 e passe o valor 'Agosto' para o campo mês. E assim sucessivamente com todos os registros do campo Data. Como fazer isto?

Comment: Muito Obrigado ao pessoal que postou. Consegui na primeira tentativa utilizando o tópico citado por Gustavo Cinque: `SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR';
UPDATE tabela SET Mes = (MONTHNAME(Data)) WHERE Mes IS NULL;` Muito Obrigado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O necessário seria criar o campo, a coluna:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela ADD COLUMN mes VARCHAR(255);
```

E depois disso executar o update:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR';
UPDATE tabela SET mes = (SELECT MONTHNAME(data)) WHERE mes IS NULL;
```

Isso gerará o mês em extenso em Português.

Comment: Por que do select na definição do mês ?

Comment: O select seleciona a data na row em que está apontado. 
Eu pensei assim para fazer, não sei se existe uma forma sem o SELECT

Comment: Basta `MONTHNAME(data)`

Comment: Não há nenhuma inconsistência com as várias rows?

Comment: Não, o update vai atualizar todas linhas nulas (`where`), linha por linha individualmente.

Comment: Hm, não sabia, mas funcionou normal aqui.

Comment: DEU CERTO com este citado por Gustavo Cinque:
SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR';
UPDATE tabela SET Mes = (MONTHNAME(Data)) WHERE Mes IS NULL;

Muito Obrigado

Answer (score 4):

Pode criar um consulta que gere os update assim

```
set lc_time_names = 'pt_BR';

SELECT concat('UPDATE tabela SET mes_extenso = \'', monthname(data), '\' WHERE id =', id)
FROM datas
```

[lc_time_names](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/locale-support.html), define o locale que é o responsavel por traduzir o nome do mês em português e [monthname()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname) retorna o nome do mês por extenso a partir de uma data:

```
select monthname(now())
```

saida:

```
Agosto ou august
```

**[Exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/28571/2/0)**

Comment: não conhecia o lc_time_names

Comment: Vou realizar os testes e informo aqui se deu certo.

Answer (score 2):

Altere sua tabela no banco de Dados com `alter table`

```
ALTER TABLE `tabela` 
ADD COLUMN `mes` VARCHAR(12) NULL;
```

Em seguida, de um `update` nessa tabela, com a sua data:

```
UPDATE `tabela` SET `mes` = date_format(`data`, '%M')
```

Isso irá popular a coluna `mes` com o mês em extenso em inglês.

Um segundo update pode ser necessário para traduzir para português, algo parecido com isso:

```
UPDATE `tabela` SET `mes` =
CASE mes
  WHEN 'January'   THEN 'Janeiro'
  WHEN 'February'  THEN 'Fevereiro'
  WHEN 'March'     THEN 'Março'
  WHEN 'April'     THEN 'Abril'
  WHEN 'May'       THEN 'Maio'
  WHEN 'June'      THEN 'Junho'
  WHEN 'July'      THEN 'Julho'
  WHEN 'August'    THEN 'Agosto'
  WHEN 'September' THEN 'Setembro'
  WHEN 'October'   THEN 'Outubro'
  WHEN 'November'  THEN 'Novembro'
  WHEN 'December'  THEN 'Dezembro'
ELSE `mes`;
```

---

Alternativamente, antes do `update`, você pode usar o `lc_time_names` para não precisar traduzir o nome dos meses:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR';

UPDATE `tabela` SET `mes` = date_format(`data`, '%M')
```

Comment: Vou realizar os testes e informo aqui se deu certo.

Answer (score 1):

Gravando na base em algum campo:

```
update tabela1 set dataextenso = (CASE month(data) 
         when 1 then 'Janeiro'
         when 2 then 'Fevereiro'
         when 3 then 'Março'
         when 4 then 'Abril'
         when 5 then 'Maio'
         when 6 then 'Junho'
         when 7 then 'Julho'
         when 8 then 'Agosto'
         when 9 then 'Setembro'
         when 10 then 'Outubro'
         when 11 then 'Novembro'
         when 12 then 'Dezembro'
         END)
```

Sem gravar na base:

```
Select id, data, mes
FROM (
SELECT
      day(data) AS dia,
      year(data) AS ano,    
      (CASE month(data) 
         when 1 then 'Janeiro'
         when 2 then 'Fevereiro'
         when 3 then 'Março'
         when 4 then 'Abril'
         when 5 then 'Maio'
         when 6 then 'Junho'
         when 7 then 'Julho'
         when 8 then 'Agosto'
         when 9 then 'Setembro'
         when 10 then 'Outubro'
         when 11 then 'Novembro'
         when 12 then 'Dezembro'
         END) AS mes,
         id, 
         data 
FROM tabela1
WHERE not (data is null)
) as tabela1
```

Outra sem gravar na base:

```
Select id, data, mes
FROM (
SELECT
      day(data) AS dia,
      year(data) AS ano,    
      (CASE monthname(data) 
         when 'January' then 'Janeiro'
         when 'February' then 'Fevereiro'
         when 'March' then 'Março'
         when 'April' then 'Abril'
         when 'May' then 'Maio'
         when 'June' then 'Junho'
         when 'July' then 'Julho'
         when 'August' then 'Agosto'
         when 'September' then 'Setembro'
         when 'October' then 'Outubro'
         when 'November' then 'Novembro'
         when 'December' then 'Dezembro'
         END) AS mes,
         id, 
         data 
FROM tabela1
WHERE not (data is null)
) as tabela1
```

Comment: Acredito que o Rodrigo queira criar uma coluna mês na tabela, não exibir em um `select`.

Comment: @gmsantos eu ainda estava formulando a resposta, mas, obrigada

Comment: Isto mesmo gmsantos, eu vou testar como você colocou abaixo e retorno se der algo errado ou certo.

Comment: @RodrigoSegatto está com 3 soluções, só uma pergunta pra que gravar esse informação, não é irrelevante visto que sem você guardar você tem ela do mesmo jeito, qual a finalidade, fiquei curiosa?

Comment: Estou realizando um trabalho de Mineração de Dados em Meu TCC e preciso da base de dados melhor estruturada, caso contrário ficam milhares de linhas de data uma diferente da outra, e desta forma não ajudaria no processo.

Comment: @RodrigoSegatto entendi, boa sorte no seu TCC.

Answer (score 0):

Não precisa mexer no SQL, o segredo é deixar os dados puros. Veja o exemplo em PHP, crio apenas um array e jogo manualmente os meses em string começando do 1.

```
$query = "SELECT Year(date) as ano, MONTH(date) as mes, DAY(date) as dia, guitarwars.* FROM guitarwars WHERE approved = 1 ORDER BY score DESC, date ASC";
```

daí crio um array $mes:

```
$mes = array(1 => "Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro");
```

então você joga o valor do mês dentro do chamado do array:

```
echo 'Mes ' . $mes[$row['mes']];
```

Não precisa bater cabeça em nada, e isso é até uma boa prática.