# Select com o dia da semana em português

Tags: mysql, sql

Boa tarde Pessoal, preciso fazer um select que traduza o dia da semana para português, já está funcionando, mas em inglês. Como posso mudar.

```
Select *,id, data, mes,date_format(`data`,'%d/%m/%Y') as `data_formatada` FROM (SELECT DAYNAME(data) AS dia, year(data) AS ano,    
                    (CASE month(data) 
                       when 1 then 'Janeiro'
                       when 2 then 'Fevereiro'
                       when 3 then 'Março'
                       when 4 then 'Abril'
                       when 5 then 'Maio'
                       when 6 then 'Junho'
                       when 7 then 'Julho'
                       when 8 then 'Agosto'
                       when 9 then 'Setembro'
                       when 10 then 'Outubro'
                       when 11 then 'Novembro'
                       when 12 then 'Dezembro'
                       END) AS mes,
                       id, 
                       data,hora,evento,participante FROM agenda WHERE not (data is null)) as agenda
```

Obrigado.

Comment: Opa, estou usando mysql

Comment: Relacionado: [Converter dados de campo Data para Mês Mysql](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30474/91)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar a função **weekday**(data) pra saber o dia da semana  e a solução vai ser semelhante ao que você fez para o mês .

Ela considera o dia da semana como um inteiro de **0 - 6** começando por segunda feira e indo até domingo.

Segue uma solução:

```
Select *,id, data, mes,date_format(`data`,'%d/%m/%Y') as `data_formatada` FROM (SELECT DAYNAME(data) AS dia, year(data) AS ano,    
                    (CASE month(data) 
                       when 1 then 'Janeiro'
                       when 2 then 'Fevereiro'
                       when 3 then 'Março'
                       when 4 then 'Abril'
                       when 5 then 'Maio'
                       when 6 then 'Junho'
                       when 7 then 'Julho'
                       when 8 then 'Agosto'
                       when 9 then 'Setembro'
                       when 10 then 'Outubro'
                       when 11 then 'Novembro'
                       when 12 then 'Dezembro'
                       END) AS mes,
 (CASE WEEKDAY(data) 
                       when 0 then 'Segunda-feira'
                       when 1 then 'Terça-feira'
                       when 2 then 'Quarta-feira'
                       when 3 then 'Quinta-feira'
                       when 4 then 'Sexta-feira'
                       when 5 then 'Sábado'
                       when 6 then 'Domingo'                 
                       END) AS DiaDaSemana,
                       id, 
                       data,hora,evento,participante FROM agenda WHERE not (data is null)) as agenda
```

Comment: Isso mesmo amigo. Obrigado.

Answer (score 9):

Basta você usar `lc_time_names = 'pt_PT';`

```
SET lc_time_names = 'pt_PT';

Select  DAYNAME(NOW()) AS dia, year(NOW()) AS ano,    
    (CASE month(NOW()) 
       when 1 then 'Janeiro'
       when 2 then 'Fevereiro'
       when 3 then 'Março'
       when 4 then 'Abril'
       when 5 then 'Maio'
       when 6 then 'Junho'
       when 7 then 'Julho'
       when 8 then 'Agosto'
       when 9 then 'Setembro'
       when 10 then 'Outubro'
       when 11 then 'Novembro'
       when 12 then 'Dezembro'
       END) AS mes
```

Resumindo você só precisa mesmo.

```
SET lc_time_names = 'pt_PT';

Select  DAYNAME(NOW()) AS dia, year(NOW()) AS ano,     MONTHNAME(NOW()) AS mes
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Bem mais simples.

Comment: Porque não usou a função `MONTHNAME()` também no nome do mês? [+1]

Comment: Mas está na resposta.

Comment: ignore este newba medíocre, perdão :)

Comment: Funcionou também cara. Muito obrigado.

Comment: Essa deveria ser a resposta aceita.