# MySQL IReport DATE_FORMAT meses em português

Tags: mysql, ireport

Tenho alguns gráficos usando `IReport`, em um deles precisava mostrar a data em formato "mês/ano".
Utilizando o código:

`DATE_FORMAT(data,'%m/%y') as mesAno`

consigo apenas mostrar no formato inglês (conforme imagem abaixo), porém preciso no formato "pt BR" por exemplo: ago/2015, mai/2015.

Não queria mexer nas configurações do MySQL para isso.

Exemplo do gráfico:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse trecho de código possibilita mostrar os nomes dos meses em "pt BR".

```
 CASE MONTHNAME(data) "
                    + "when 'January' then 'Janeiro'\n"
                    + "when 'February' then 'Fevereiro'\n"
                    + "when 'March' then 'Março'\n"
                    + "when 'April' then 'Abril'\n"
                    + "when 'May' then 'Maio'\n"
                    + "when 'June' then 'Junho'\n"
                    + "when 'July' then 'Julho'\n"
                    + "when 'August' then 'Agosto'\n"
                    + "when 'September' then 'Setembro'\n"
                    + "when 'November' then 'Novembro'\n"
                    + "when 'December' then 'Dezembro'"
                    + " END as mes
```

Teria algo assim para o formato mês/ano?

Encontrei em alguns sites este código:
`SET lc_time_names = "pt_br" ;` 
Mas não encontrei como aplicar na minha `query`.

Se alguém puder ajudar, obrigado.

Comment: Possível duplicata de: [Converter dados de campo Data para Mês Mysql](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30474/91)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a ideia que você passou, juntando com o ano, usando CONCAT.
Exemplo:

```
SELECT CASE MONTHNAME(data) "
                + "when 'January' then 'Janeiro'\n"
                + "when 'February' then 'Fevereiro'\n"
                + "when 'March' then 'Março'\n"
                + "when 'April' then 'Abril'\n"
                + "when 'May' then 'Maio'\n"
                + "when 'June' then 'Junho'\n"
                + "when 'July' then 'Julho'\n"
                + "when 'August' then 'Agosto'\n"
                + "when 'September' then 'Setembro'\n"
                + "when 'November' then 'Novembro'\n"
                + "when 'December' then 'Dezembro'"
                + " END as mes, 
DATE_FORMAT(data,'%y') as ano,
CONCAT(mes, '/', ano) as mesAno
FROM suatabela
```

Ou seja, você pega os campos que definiu antes, separadamente, e junta eles com CONCAT.

Uma outra forma mais enxuta de traduzir os meses via SELECT do mysql seria assim (apos testes locais, a funcao deve estar dentro do CONCAT, não sendo entendido como campo extra):

```
SELECT CONCAT(ELT(MONTH(data), 'Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'), '/', YEAR(data)) as mesAno FROM suatabela GROUP BY YEAR(data), MONTH(data) ORDER BY data
```

Comment: Eu até pensei em algo neste sentido, mas, creio que traria complicações na hora de setar a categoria do gráfico: .`setCategory(mesAno)`, não sei como faria. E também no `GROUP BY mesAno`. O que acha?

Comment: Categoria não tem a ver com eixo.  Você pode ter várias categorias num gráfico dentro do mesmo eixo.

Comment: Em relação ao group by, você vai usar diretamente o campo da base de dados: 
GROUP BY YEAR(data), MONTH(data)
... ou ... 
GROUP BY date_format(data, '%Y-%m')

Comment: Vou averiguar aqui, e posto os resultados.

Comment: Vou editar a minha resposta acima para mostrar mais uma forma, que é mais enxuta...

Comment: @ Marcelo Gomes Sua segunda opção funcionou corretamente! A apresentou erro  `unknown field mes in field list`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39551/discussion-between-rodrigo-and-marcelo-gomes).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode ver o valor atual da variável com o uso do comando SELECT, do MySQL:

```
SELECT @@lc_time_names;

+-----------------+
| @@lc_time_names |
+-----------------+
| pt_BR           |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

e use o comando SET para alterar a variável:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'pt_BR';
```

Agora, faça o teste:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2020-08-06', '%d de %M de %Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

Defina o locale, talvez seja necessário instalar a versão pt-BR

```
setlocale(LC_TIME,"portuguese"); 
DATE('%m/%y')
```

Comment: @ Saimita tentei muito usar o `LC_TIME` , mas não consegui, no caso da sua sugestão, onde colocaria este código: `setlocale(LC_TIME,"portuguese");`?